# Просветительная и просветительская

Tags: стилистика, лексика

В чем их отличие?

Согласно некоторым источникам "просветительская" - принадлежащая тому, кто просвещает, - просветителю. "Просветительная" - направленная на просвещение. Путаница, да и только.
Например, просветительная работа для родителей. Думаю, этот вариант верен.

Comment: Это слова-паронимы. У каждого своё значение.

Answer (score 1):

> > > Согласно некоторым источникам "просветительская" - принадлежащая тому, кто просвещает, - просветителю. "Просветительная" - направленная на просвещение.

Всё так. Никакой путаницы. Другое дело, что во многих случаях подходят оба варианта.
"Просветительская" ведь не только принадлежащая просветителю, а ещё и свойсвенная ему, этот вариант более частый. "Просветительская деятельность" - деятельность просветителя.

> > > Просветительная работа для родителей

О чем речь? Очень может быть, что и "просветительская".

Comment: Директор проводит просветительскую работу для родителей (контекст)

Comment: Ох, опять эти канцеляризмы...
Здесь и так и так можно. Хотя смысл несколько разный.
Если кто-то (во главе с директором-организатором) просвещает родителей, то скорее **просветительная**. Если они же учат родителей как просвещать детей (т.е. быть просветителями), то **просветительская**.   
Но здесь различия не настолько велики, чтобы придираться.

Answer (score 0):

ПРОСВЕТИТЕЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое.
1.
Служащий просвещению;распространяющий знания. П. кружок. **П-ая работа.**
2.
Связанный с учениями и деятельностью представителей эпохи Просвещения или просветительства. П-ие идеи
(о просветительских учениях 17 - 18 вв.). П-ая философия.

ПРОСВЕТИТЕЛЬСКИЙ, -ая, -ое.
к Просветитель и Просветительство. **П-ая деятельность.** П-ие идеи.

(Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова. С "Грамоты")

**Просветитель - 1.Распространитель знаний, просвещения**.2.Представитель т. наз. Эпохи просвещения в 18 в. и русского просветительства середины 19 века (истор.)

Разницу видите? Я -нет. Надо признать, что эти слова в данном контексте являются синонимами.

Comment: Я вижу.  
Уже говорил. Просветительная - связанная с просвещением. Просветительская - с просветителями.

Часто различия несущественны. Но могут быть и тонкости. Скажем, "просветительский талант". Явно не "просветительный".

Comment: Мой вопрос только по отношению к выделенным словосочетаниям. Просветительная работа - просветительская деятельность с учетом первого значения слова просветитель. А про талант - конечно, согласна.

Comment: Ммммм.... Боюсь, что в более широком контексте могут проявиться различия. Вот с тем же "организовывать".
"Организовать просветительную деятельность" - это по части организации просвещения.  
А "просветительскую" - все что угодно, вплоть до организации питания и отдыха просветителей.